# Follow redirects for image HTTP request, client-side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

You know this link:

```
http://media.photobucket.com/image/graphics/PennilessTeacher/Graphics/monster.jpg?o=8
```

redirects to this link:

```
http://i1133.photobucket.com/albums/m581/PennilessTeacher/Graphics/monster.jpg
```

Well, let's say I have:

```
<img src='http://media.photobucket.com/image/graphics/PennilessTeacher/Graphics/monster.jpg?o=8' width='blah' height = 'blah'/>
```

The request to the image URL will be redirected. I want to know the **end** URL. So in this case, it would be `http://i1133.photobucket.com/albums/m581/PennilessTeacher/Graphics/monster.jpg`.

I previously asked a question about fetching the status code of a cross domain image request, which seems to be impossible without a server side script doing the `http` request.

Server side scripts are out of the question here. I need the request to be processed on the client's side, as some of the sites the image element will be pointing to require some specific cookies that sit on the client side, which I obviously cannot help myself to as they're for a completely different domain. If that makes any sense...

Any client side language will do. Whether I know it or not.

Suggestions people? Or am I totally screwed?

Comment: Why can't you pass those cookies to your server-side script, and let it follow the redirects?  Are they session specific (and therefore dependent on coming from your IP)?  You could do this with AJAX, even as the images are being loaded on the page.

Comment: But those cookies don't belong to me (my domain) @Brad. So the browser won't let me play with them :(

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  Yeah, that won't work.

Comment: I would say xmlHttpRequest, but pretty sure that doesnt like out of domain requests.

Comment: @Raiden, AJAX transparently follows redirects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get that information using client side scripting. The only information in the DOM is the originally requested URI.

(If it was possible then information could be leaked. e.g. if `http://example.com/me` redirected to `http://example.com/users/username` and expose Alice's username on Bob's site to Malory (who ran the website with `<img src="http://example.com/me">` on it when Alice visited that site … or perhaps it might redirect to `http://cdn.example.com/alices/private/content/protected/by/time/limited/key/h4io3foiu32if390f490` and let Malory get access to Alice's private content).

Comment: Well that sucks. Is there **any** way of following a redirect of a cross-domain request client side? I know of `JSONP`, but the sites I'm playing around with won't support them.

Comment: Follow? Yes. Exposing the URI of that to the site owner - absolutely not.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but can this be a solution or even is it what you are asking...
suppose you know the url...create a server side file(.php in my case) that takes the url from the client side(with ajax or whatever) and uses curl to obtain the image site...then, find the img tag with the id=fullSizedImage and get the src of it...as i said i'm not sure whether is this you are asking...

Comment: It needs to be done through the client side as the destination site requires specific cookies to load the image. Those cookies a stored on the client's browser for a different domain, So I can't access those cookies either. Which is why the `http` request needs to be processed through the client's side.