# Get URL after more variables are added

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to get data from a Website which doesn't offer a API. But the data I need is attatched to the url after processing the request.

As an example: https://www.google.com/maps?q=bundesplatz%201%20Bern in the end is going to be https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bundesplatz+1,+3011+Bern,+Schweiz/@46.9471068,7.4427224,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x478e39c6d8bfeddd:0xae3ec66e50957386

Is there a way to store the second url as a variable after an ajax request?

Comment: So you are looking for a function that converts a "placename" into coordinates? This sounds like a messy solution for something the google maps api is able to do easily?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713416/follow-redirects-for-image-http-request-client-side